# Is there any XML.ecore file available to use

Tags: xml, eclipse-emf, ecore

I am looking to see if there is any ready to use xml.ecore file. By this, I mean an ecore metamodel of xml documents.

Comment: seems somebody is unhappy about this question. I would appreciate if you clarify why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found XML.Ecore file. In this [metamodel zoo](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/atlanmod/index.php/Ecore#XML_1.1) you can find xml.ecore besides many other metamodels.